# Euro symbol(€) is displayed as $ by Stanford NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

We are trying to extract the EURO value from the document. Stanford is recognizing the money as expected. However it is during extracting it is converting € to $.

[image]

Comment: Where in the process does this occur? I'm not familiar with Stanford NLP, but is this the result of one action? In that case the problem lies with Standford.

Comment: I've never used stanford, but a simple search shows this:  [standford documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml) _"normalizeCurrency: Whether to do some awful lossy currency mappings to turn common currency characters into $, #, or "cents", reflecting the fact that nothing else appears in the old PTB3 WSJ. (No Euro!) Default is true."_

Comment: Why the `C#` tag? Anyway, it's up to the program that displays the value to format it appropriatelly. Numbers don't have currencies. The program decides how to display it. Some have hard-coded locales, some use the *user's* locale. Either your locale is US or the program doesn't check the user's locale

Comment: Yes. After fetching the result the symbol is getting converted. May be the problem with the Stanford. Just wanna know whether it can be solved or not. Thankyou

Comment: @Madhu solve what? You haven't provided any information. I'm removing the `c#` tag anyway since it's unrelated

Comment: Did you happen to discover other Easter eggs in Stanford CoreNLP? I mean those that change the meaning. I was really scared when I saw euro sign turned to dollar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample command to run Stanford CoreNLP and turn off the currency normalization:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit -file sample-sentence.txt -outputFormat text -tokenize.options "normalizeCurrency=false"
```

Comment: Thanks. can you please tell how to set it programatically in C#

Comment: Is there a reason why this so called normalization is ON by default? Euro and Dollars are completely different currencies, at least at present.

Comment: For me, the tokenizer cannot recognize the Euro character with it off.  It is represented by the character "¬" and not recognized as MONEY or a NUMBER in NER,  There is even a No Euro! comment on the [Stanford Tokenizer](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml) page.  Perhaps it has to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using corenlp as a dedicated server, you can include -tokenize.options parameter in url when sending the request.
Eg.

```html
http://corenlp.run?properties={"timeout":"36000","annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,parse,lemma,ner,regexner","tokenize.options":"normalizeCurrency=false,invertible=true"}
```